# How to refresh recyclerview adapter from other recyclerview adapter in same fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, api

I have Recyclerview category and Recyclerview product in one fragment (drawer activity).
when i click something in category, i want to reload/refresh recyclerview product.
[image]

Recyclerview category

```
...
     @Override
    public transaksibaru_kategori_viewholder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item_transaksibaru_kategori, parent, false);
        final transaksibaru_kategori_viewholder vHolder = new transaksibaru_kategori_viewholder(view);
        sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(parent.getContext());
        Activity_transaksibaru.KEY_ACT = "run";
        vHolder.linearlayout_kategori.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String id_kategori = mItem_kategori.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getId();
                sharedPrefManager.savetransaksibarustring(SharedPrefManager.sp_idkategori,id_kategori);
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "ID KATEGORI = " + id_kategori,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        return vHolder;
    }
...
```

Fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

        statusview = sharedPrefManager.getSp_viewmode();
        statushitung = Integer.valueOf(statusview);
        id_kategori = sharedPrefManager.getSp_idkategori();
        //id_kategori = "10";
        if (statushitung%2 == 0){
            call_itembarang_gridview();
            i=1;
        }else {
            call_itembarang();
            i=2;
        }
...
```

I just need to run call_itembarang() from RV_category(RV2) it must be simple but i dont know how to do that

Comment: where do you create the recyclerview adapter?

Comment: @svi.data same directory with that fragment

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your problem would be:

1. Keep both adapters(productsAdapter and categoryAdapter) in
   SharedPrefManager.
2. Add loadCategory(int categoryId) method to SharedPrefManager.

   ```
   public void loadCategory(int categoryId) {
       // you need to create getProductsOfCategory method in SharedPrefManager.
       List<Product> products = getProductsOfCategory(categoryId);
       // you need to create setProductList method in productsAdapter
       productsAdapter.setProductList(products);
       productsAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
   }
   ```
3. In the RecyclerView of categories, in onCreateViewHolder method change your onClickListener so that it uses loadCategory method.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a case where the adapter must communicate with fragment.

we will use an interface for that:

**1) create an interface in a new file**

```
public interface onCategoryClickedListener{

void onCategoryClicked(String categoryId);

}
```

**2) the adapter**

```
public class YourAdapter extends ......{

private onCategoryClickedListener listener;


//method to set listener
public void setOnCategoryClickedListener(onCategoryClickedListener listener){
this.listener=listener;
}

//oncreateviewholder

@Override
public transaksibaru_kategori_viewholder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

......

vHolder.linearlayout_kategori.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

//your category id
final String id_kategori = mItem_kategori.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getId();

//send the category id back to your fragment
listner.onCategoryClicked(id_kategori);

            }
        });


}
```

**3) now let your fragment implement this interface**

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements onCategoryClickedListener{

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private YourAdapter adapter;
.....
.....
.....

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

.......

//here you pass the listener to your adapter

adapter.setOnCategoryClickedListener(this);

........
return(view);
}

@Override
public void onCategoryClicked(String categoryId){

//this will be called every time an item in your category is clicked

//call the method from here and whatever if statements you want

}

}
```